# why are cyclic dienes much more reactive?

Tags: organic-chemistry, pericyclic

Cyclic dienes are very reactive, for example cyclopentadiene in room temperature, it even dimerizes.

What is the factor that indicates such reactivity of cyclic dienes ?

Comment: They are fixed in the s-cis conformation, which is required for the Diels-Alder reaction. Whereas acyclic dienes can flip back and forth between the s-cis (reactive) and s-trans (unreactive) conformations

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5289/a-few-questions-about-the-conditions-of-the-diels-alder-reactions